# Create a custom dialog with radio buttons list

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-dialog

I've got a method in which i have a list of values:

```
     /**
     * ISO
     * */
    public void getISO(View view) {
        // Open dialog with radio buttons
        List<String> supported_isos = preview.getSupportedISOs();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        String current_iso = sharedPreferences.getString(MainActivity.getISOPreferenceKey(), "auto");

    }
```

This method is enjected on onClick() of a `ImageButton`:

```
android:onClick="getISO"
```

But i need to rapresent this list in a dialog with radio buttons. Possibly the preference values should be already selected in the dialog.. Is it possible?

Comment: This is possible, it all comes down to how you populate the dialog.

Comment: create a dialog and set custom view to it.

Comment: Can you show me an example using mine List please?

Comment: Start here @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: If you're looking for a simpler solution that doesn't require a custom view, check out my solution, will give you the same experience of the standard android alert dialogs, if you're not trying to do something outside of that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Call `showRadioButtonDialog()` from the button.

This is just an example:

```
private void showRadioButtonDialog() {

 // custom dialog

  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
  List<String> stringList=new ArrayList<>();  // here is list
      for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
          if (i==0){
              stringList.add("Number Mode");
          }else {
              stringList.add("Character Mode");
          }

      }

      RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

      for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
            RadioButton rb=new RadioButton(this); // dynamically creating RadioButton and adding to RadioGroup.
            rb.setText(stringList.get(i));
            rg.addView(rb);
      }
}
```

**Your layout view might be**:`radiobutton_dialog.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
      <RadioGroup
          android:id="@+id/radio_group"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="vertical">
    </RadioGroup>
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Note:** you can customize your dialog view (like setting title, message etc.)

**Edit:**
To retrieving value of the selected `RadioButton` you have to implement `setOnCheckedChangeListener` listener for your `RadioGroup` as :

```
 rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                 int childCount = group.getChildCount();
                 for (int x = 0; x < childCount; x++) {
                    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(x);
                    if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {
                         Log.e("selected RadioButton->",btn.getText().toString());

                    }
                 }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I would say for his use-case it seems a little overkill to create a custom dialog. But definitely still a possibility.

Comment: check Edit for retrieving value of selected radio button.

Answer (score 77):

best and easy way......

```
void dialog(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //alt_bld.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Group Name");
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(grpname, -1, new DialogInterface
                .OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Group Name = "+grpname[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();// dismiss the alertbox after chose option

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();


///// grpname is a array where data is stored... 


    }
```

Comment: it's not custom, it's a default alert dialog with single choice items

Comment: If you want a 'Confirm' button, just add it normally to the dialog with eg `setPositiveButton` and remove `dialog.dismiss()` from the above code.

Answer (score 9):

A clean way is like this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

### Excerpt from (Adding a persistent multiple-choice or single-choice list)

```
mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
// Set the dialog title
builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_toppings)
// Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
// and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
       .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.toppings, null,
                  new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                   boolean isChecked) {
               if (isChecked) {
                   // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                   mSelectedItems.add(which);
               } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                   // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it 
                   mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
               }
           }
       })
// Set the action buttons
       .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
               // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
               ...
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               ...
           }
       });

return builder.create();
```

Read about 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems(int, int, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems(int,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener))

No custom view is necessary.

Comment: well, author mentioned about custom

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Option-1", "Option-2", "Option-3", "Option-4"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowDialog.this);
builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog with ListView and Radio button");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
   Toast.makeText(ShowDialog.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 });
builder.setNegativeButton("No",
 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
   Toast.makeText(ShowDialog.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin version:

```
fun dialog() {
    val options = arrayOf("option1", "option2")
    var selectedItem = 0
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Select an option")
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(options
            , 0, { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, item: Int ->
        selectedItem = item
    })
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, p1: Int ->
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "selected item = " + options[selectedItem], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialogInterface.dismiss()
    })
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, p1: Int ->
        dialogInterface.dismiss()
    })
    builder.create()
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this.
This is the Custom row dialog_row.xml that you should use in CustomAdapter:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then in onclick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout); //Your custom layout
    dialog.setTitle("Title...");


    Listview listview= (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(context,your_list);
    listview.setadapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Do something

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

[Link for the tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Answer (score 0):

when you want to show data from SQLIte database the

```
private void showRadioButtonDialog() {

    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.radiobutton_dialog);
    List<String> stringList=new ArrayList<>();  // here is list 

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String a=( cursor.getString(0).toString());
            String b=(cursor.getString(1).toString());
            String c=(cursor.getString(2).toString());
            String d=(cursor.getString(3).toString());
            stringList.add(d);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());        
    }   

    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++) {
        RadioButton rb=new RadioButton(this); // dynamically creating RadioButton and adding to RadioGroup.
        rb.setText(stringList.get(i));
        rg.addView(rb);
    }

    dialog.show();

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             int childCount = group.getChildCount();
             for (int x = 0; x < childCount; x++) {
                 RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(x);
                 if (btn.getId() == checkedId) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), btn.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jetpack Compose in android-

```
AlertDialog(onDismissRequest = { viewModel.shouldDialogOpen.value = false },

            title= { "title" },
            text = {
                Column {
                    Text(
                        text = "Filter by Title Or Date",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        color = Color.Black,
                        fontSize = 16.sp
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

                    radioOptions.forEach { text ->
                        Row(
                            Modifier
                                // using modifier to add max
                                // width to our radio button.
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                // below method is use to add
                                // selectable to our radio button.
                                .selectable(
                                    // this method is called when
                                    // radio button is selected.
                                    selected = (text == viewModel.selectedFilter.value),
                                    onClick = { viewModel.onFilterSelected(text) }
                                    // below method is called on
                                    // clicking of radio button.
                                )
                                // below line is use to add
                                // padding to radio button.
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

                        ) {
                            // below line is use to get context.

                            // below line is use to
                            // generate radio button
                            RadioButton(
                                // inside this method we are
                                // adding selected with a option.
                                selected = (text == viewModel.selectedFilter.value),
                                onClick = {
                                    // inide on click method we are setting a
                                    // selected option of our radio buttons.
                                    viewModel.onFilterSelected(text)

                                },
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(top = 16.dp)
                                    .alignBy(FirstBaseline)

                            )
                            // below line is use to add
                            // text to our radio buttons.
                            Text(
                                text = text,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.merge(),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(top = 16.dp)
                                    .alignBy(FirstBaseline)
                            )
                        }
                    }

                }
            },


            confirmButton = {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), onClick = {
                    viewModel.shouldDialogOpen.value = false
                }) {
                    Text(text = "OKay")
                }
            }
        )
```

Here `radioOptions` is the list of strings for your radiobutton's label/text

and  `viewModel.shouldDialogOpen`
where shouldDialogOpen is a mutablestate field inside viewmodel whose value we change when we need to show or dismiss dialog.

For more code samples for Jetpack Compose,refer this- https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2021/08/03/jetpack-compose-1-0-0-sample-codes/