# how to create Popupmenu with radio button

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-custom-view, popupmenu

I am trying to create a `popup menu` with a radio I couldn't find any solution. I want to show a custom `popup menu` something like this

[image]

this is what I tried so far

```
imgmenuoption.setOnClickListener {
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(mContext, it)
            popupMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popupMenu.menu)
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.action_logout -> logout()
                    R.id.action_setting -> startActivity(Intent(mContext, SettingActivity::class.java))
                }
                true
            })
            popupMenu.show()
        }
```

this is showing the popup menu but how can I show the radio button before text single selection

Please help me

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: See this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520850/create-a-custom-dialog-with-radio-buttons-list

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: https://denofdevelopers.com/android-dialog-with-radio-group-and-list-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used [Balloon](https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon) library `customListBalloon` it solve my problem